# Segment Routing Encapsulation on Client Interface?

Tags: routing, ipv6, tunnel

I wanted to test SRv6. Always between two clients (client 1 <-> client 2).
If I do the encapsulation on the client everything works smooth as expected.

Client 1 (encap SRv6 Tunnel) <- 2001::/64-> Router 1 <- 2002::/64 -> Router 2 <- 2003::/64 -> Client 2

```
ip -6 route add  2003::/64 dev eth0 encap seg6 mode encap segs 2001::1,2002::2
```

If I do the encapsulation on the router and use a default route on the client it no longer works so smooth.

Client 1 <- 2001::/64-> Router 1 (encap SRv6 Tunnel) <- 2002::/64 -> Router 2 <- 2003::/64 -> Client 2

- Ping works
- iperf3 connection works in reverse mode (since we have a flow label)
- iperf3 forward connection does no longer work

```
ip -6 route add  2003::/64 dev eth0 encap seg6 mode encap seg 2002::2
```

Any idea, why this is the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer as asked. We need details, such as the network device models and configurations. Please edit the question to include enough information to answer the question.